# Should Laravel Eloquent Model observer events return the object?

Tags: laravel, events, eloquent, laravel-5.5

For example

```
namespace App\Observers;

use App\Models\User;

class UserObserver
{

    public function saving(User $user)
    {
        $user->epoch = time();

        $user->save(); // or even this
        return $user; // should I do this or not?
    }    
}
```

I cannot find any good documentation about the model events when they are called and what to put inside it.

Comment: No, it shouldn't. Why do you want to return any result from a listener? You usually just modify some data, writing some data to the log file etc.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Because it is not very clear if the chain of events continues, if the listener callback expects an object etc. It just is not very clear to me.

Comment: These listeners are not chained, so don't worry. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too have been unable to find proper documentation on this but after some testing, I can confirm that you do not need to return the object, or anything, in fact.

The object passed in as the parameter ***IS*** the object being modified so, in your case, you don't need either of the last two lines. Just set the value of `$user->epoch` and move along.

That said, you would probably be better served setting this value in a mutator. To do so, just add the following to your `User` model:

`public function setEpochAttribute() {
    $this->attributes['epoch'] = time();
}`

Again, no need to return anything.

I find it helpful to maintain values of attributes in mutators because, in the case of tests where you aren't necessarily saving to the database, the values will still be correct. Maybe try thinking of observers as your last line of defense prior to committing to the database or as the first horse out of the gate (for -ed actions) following a database action.

Thanks to [Borja](https://www.linkedin.com/in/borja-brisson-a2064846/) for his input on this. Couldn't have answered this without him :-)

Answer (score 3):

The laravel model events available are theses :

`retrieved, creating, created, updating, updated, saving, saved, deleting, deleted,  restoring, restored`

the `ed` ones are called once the event is over
the `ing` one are called just before the event is launch

exemple :

creating will affect your model before getting created (object not in database yet, so no id)
created, is called after it as been create into the database (you can get his id)

when you are using this:

$model->save();

you can think like this :

$model->saving(do something)->save();
$model->save()->saved();